# If scripts fails, NPM should continue executing further ones

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, protractor

I have following script in my package.json file which I execute in my cmd by **npm run protractor**:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install",
    "pretest": "npm install",
    "test": "karma start test/karma.conf.js",
    "test-single-run": "karma start test/karma.conf.js  --single-run",
    "preupdate-webdriver": "npm install",
    "update-webdriver": "webdriver-manager update",
    "preprotractor": "npm run update-webdriver && node setUp.js",
    "protractor": "protractor test/protractor-conf.js",
    "postprotractor": "node tearDown.js",
  }
```

If all my e2e test pass, npm runs the entire script - also my tearDown.js. However, in the event of a failure in my protractor tests ("protractor": "protractor test/protractor-conf.js"), npm does not continue to execute my postprotractor file(I need tearDown.js as it closes my backend). 
Is there any solution of making npm run the **entire** script?

Answer (score 2):

You should run your setup script and teardown script as part of protractor in [beforeLaunch](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js#L178) and [afterLaunch](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js#L221), not npm.

If for some reason you absolutely do not want to run it as part of protractor you would have to change the protractor exitCode to '0', either in afterLaunch ([example](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/errorTest/afterLaunchChangesExitCodeConf.js#L24)) or by wrapping a script around your protractor run script. However, I highly advise against doing this because then you're just masking errors.

Comment: Great solution! Only problem is that my backend opens up, a http request is made and protractor already opens up - however my http request is not finished yet. Do you have an idea how I can fix this time problem?

Comment: You can return a promise in beforeLaunch and protractor will wait for it.

Comment: I solved the problem using promises, thank you for your tip! However, I have one question remaining: It seems like afterLaunch ignores async code - is there any way to bypass it? As I want fully automated test cases, I put taskkill in my afterLaunch to kill my backend. I can't put the code in a seperate file and let npm run it in postprotractor (if error - backend is not closed)... Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean ignores async code? AfterLaunch works the same way as beforeLaunch.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1413 - the npm module ms-task is however async and afterLaunch just ignores it...

Comment: I used onCleanUp instead, seems to be working now. Concerning the promises - is there any other way? Something like sleep();  ?